# CAS Database schema update

Tags: cas

I'm configuring an CAS and I want to try the `QueryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler`.

Now I don't know how the database tables should be created...

Can I let the CAS create the database tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your design the schema based on the query you create and configure in CAS
https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Database-Authentication.html